# Save multiple same named fields to database PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

The PHP CODE to save it.

```
$cols = $_POST['col'];

$EvenementID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['evenementid']);

foreach($cols as $col) {

$Ticketnaam = mysql_real_escape_string($col['ticket']);
$Aantal = mysql_real_escape_string($col['aantal']);
$Prijs = mysql_real_escape_string($col['prijs']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Tickets (EvenementID, Ticketnaam, Aantal, Prijs) VALUES('".$EvenementID ."', '{$Ticketnaam}', '{$Aantal}', '{$Prijs}')";


}
```

HTML CODE

```
<input type="hidden" name="evenementid" value="<?php echo $evenementid; ?>" />
```

BLOCK 1

```
<input type="text" name="col[0][ticket]" id="ticket" class="tekst-lang"/>
<input type="text" class="tekst-lang" name="col[0][aantal]" id="aantal"/>
<input type="text" class="tekst-lang" name="col[0][prijs]" id="prijs"/>
```

BLOCK 2

```
<input type="text" name="col[1][ticket]" id="ticket" class="tekst-lang"/>
<input type="text" class="tekst-lang" name="col[1][aantal]" id="aantal"/>
<input type="text" class="tekst-lang" name="col[1][prijs]" id="prijs"/>
```

AJAX

```
var myData = $('#ticket-form').serialize();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",

                            //URL of the php file that will process the login
                            url: "includes/ticket.php",

                            dataType: 'json',

                            //Pass the data through
                            data: myData,

                            //Handle the response
                            success: function (data) {

                            switch(data.case){

                            case 1: 
                            $(".inlog-feedback").html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                            break;

                            case 2:      
                            $(".inlog-feedback").html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                            window.location = "index.php"; 
                            break;

                            case 3: 
                            $(".inlog-feedback").html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                            break;

                            default:
                            /* If none of the above */

                            }
                    }            
                        })  

                        //Stop the submit button from submitting the form 
                        return false;   
                        }
```

I'm trying to save the 2 blocks to my database (So I need 2 records). Both blocks have the same evenementID. The problem is that there is only one record in the database.

Comment: are you using ajax or a normal form submission?

Comment: can we see your ajax request code?

Comment: You need to show how `myData` is created! ah i see it got missed from the code segment.

Comment: The ajax is in the question

Comment: Do a `count($cols)` and see how many columns are actually there. if it is only one then something is wrong with the way your form is.

Comment: Major question: Do you execute your `$sql` variable inside the foreach loop? or after the loop?

Comment: When I try to count the result is 2, $Sql is inside the loop

Comment: What I mean is do you do a `mysql_query($sql)` inside your foreach loop or after the loop?

Comment: Sorry, the `mysql_query($sql)` is after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cols = $_POST['col'];

$EvenementID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['evenementid']);

foreach($cols as $col) {

$Ticketnaam = mysql_real_escape_string($col['ticket']);
$Aantal = mysql_real_escape_string($col['aantal']);
$Prijs = mysql_real_escape_string($col['prijs']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Tickets (EvenementID, Ticketnaam, Aantal, Prijs) VALUES('".$EvenementID ."', '{$Ticketnaam}', '{$Aantal}', '{$Prijs}')";

$res = mysql_query($sql);//This will execute count($cols) number of times

}
```

You need to move the mysql_query($sql) inside the loop, otherwise it will execute the last iteration of the foreach loop only.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (isset($_POST)){    
$EvenementID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['evenementid']);

foreach($_POST as $col) {

$Ticketnaam_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($col[0]['ticket']);
$Aantal_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($col[0]['aantal']);
$Prijs_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($col[0]['prijs']);


$Ticketnaam_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($col[1]['ticket']);
$Aantal_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($col[1]['aantal']);
$Prijs_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($col[1]['prijs']);





$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Tickets (EvenementID, Ticketnaam, Aantal, Prijs) VALUES('".$EvenementID ."', '{$Ticketnaam_1}', '{$Aantal_1}', '{$Prijs_1}')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Tickets (EvenementID, Ticketnaam, Aantal, Prijs) VALUES('".$EvenementID ."', '{$Ticketnaam_2}', '{$Aantal_2}', '{$Prijs_2}')";


}


}
```

Comment: This would not work due to there being more then one key in the `$_POST` array. If `$_POST['col']` was the only key, this would work limitedly.